# Dryer timer not advancing and not heating

Tags: electrical, heating, dryer, appliances, timer

Whirpool brand dryer timer not advancing at all. It’s also not heating as well. I checked the thermal fuse, thermostat and heating element by using continuity. All of them looks good as much as I can tell. I am not %100 sure about the timer itself.

I also measured the voltage at the plug and it gives 120V from hot ones to ground and neutral. It’s also 240V between hot ones. But when I plugged it, and checked power cables at the dryer side, I see only 120V’s. It doesn’t give me 240V.

Answer (score 2):

> I also measured the voltage at the plug and it gives 120V from hot ones to ground and neutral. It’s also 240V between hot ones. But when I plugged it, and checked power cables at the dryer side, I see only 120V’s. It doesn’t give me 240V.

Disconnect the cord and plug and examine it carefully with your multimeter. It would appear that you've lost continuity in the cord and plug assembly, if you have no 240V at the dryer but do on the Receptacle, and evidently it would be the same side of the line that's powering the timer.

A rarer case would be that the receptacle and plug are not mating correctly so your probe is picking up the bad leg, but the plug isn't. You can check for that with your multimeter and the circuit switched OFF if the cord manages to pass. Check for continuity from the wire at the back of the receptacle to the end of the [plugged in] cord, still not attached to the dryer. DO NOT attempt to check for voltage with the circuit ON in that condition. It's hazardous and not necessary.